# Falha de segmentação em matriz

Tags: c, matriz, cache, gcc

Estou recebendo o erro de falha de segmentação no código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define linha 1000
#define coluna 1000


int main() {

  long double M1[1000][1000];
  long double M2[1000][1000];
  long double matrizResultante[1000][1000];

    /** multiplicando a matriz **/
    for(int i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < coluna; j++) {
            matrizResultante[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < coluna; k++) {
                matrizResultante[i][j] += M1[i][k] * M2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

O objetivo desse código é analisar as taxas de acesso a memoria cache, minha suspeita é que o erro esta sendo gerado por não inicializar a matriz, mas como os valores são grandes a inicialização é inviável. Será realmente esse o problema?

Estou utilizando o gcc para compilar o código.

Comment: Não tem motivo algum pra não funcionar, e ele até funcionou (diminuí o tamanho para não dar excesso de tempo do ideone): http://ideone.com/O2n3aE O código não parece ajudar no que deseja.

Comment: bigown opa tudo certo? muito estranho aqui quando vou tentar compilar ele me joga um erro de segmentação, estou utilizando o gcc. quando você fala em o código não parece ajudar no que desejo, esta falando sobre a questão de analise de acesso a memoria cache? meu objetivo é tentar analisar a taxa de miss e hit, pelo tamanho da matriz acho que deve me ajudar nessa proposta.

Comment: Se dá *seg fault* quando compila, o problema é do GCC :P Falo disso. Até dá para usar isso, mas o experimento precisa ser bem mais controlado do que só rodar isso. Mas isso foi mais uma opinião, nem posso falar sem saber tudo o que está fazendo.

Comment: bigown pois é o problema esta no gcc, estou rodando com o codeblocks e aparentemente como você disse esta tudo certo, sobre o experimento estou usando o valgrind, meu objetivo é tentar melhorar o código, diminuir a taxas de miss.

Comment: O valor que está indo para essa matriz pode estar ficando maior do que o suportado pelo long double. Sugiro que você coloque um printf para identificar em qual ponto da iteração ocorre a falha de segmentação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A causa do problema é: **STACK OVERFLOW**.

A solução é: retirar a alocação dos enormes arrays dentro da função main, e alocar estaticamente (ou dinamicamente com malloc).

Francamente, fico abismado com essas coisas horríveis, o stack não é para ser usado dessa maneira, com essas declarações de dezenas de megabytes...precisa de arrays muito grandes ? Aloque estaticamente, ou dinamicamente com malloc.

Mais uma coisa: a convenção universal é declarar defines EM MAIÚSCULAS.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_LINHAS 1000
#define N_COLUNAS 1000

long double M1[1000][1000];
long double M2[1000][1000];
long double matrizResultante[1000][1000];

int main()
{
   /** multiplicando a matriz **/
   for (int i = 0; i < N_LINHAS; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < N_COLUNAS; j++)
      {
         matrizResultante[i][j] = 0;
         for (int k = 0; k < N_COLUNAS; k++)
         {
            matrizResultante[i][j] += M1[i][k] * M2[k][j];
         }
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiquei perplexo o rodar seu código e receber a falha de segmentação uma vez que parece correto.
Bom não descobri a causa do problema, mas descobri alguns indícios que o problema central está na alocação de memória feita pelo compilador para valores maiores que uma determinada taxa, e também descobri como você pode corrigir isso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define linha 1000
#define coluna 1000


int main() {

  /*alocação de memória */  
  long double **M1 = malloc(sizeof(long double*) * linha);
  long double **M2 = malloc(sizeof(long double*) * linha);
  long double **matrizResultante = malloc(sizeof(long double*) * linha);

  for(int i = 0; i < linha; i++){
      M1[i] = malloc(sizeof(long double) * coluna);
      M2[i] = malloc(sizeof(long double) * coluna);
      matrizResultante[i] = malloc(sizeof(long double) * coluna);
  }

    /** multiplicando a matriz **/
    for(int i = 0; i < linha; i++) {        
        for(int j = 0; j < coluna; j++) {        
            matrizResultante[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < coluna; k++) {
                matrizResultante[i][j] += M1[i][k] * M2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Bom é importante ressaltar algumas coisas:
Primeiro, a alocação é diferente da realizada pelo compilador, então no seu caso você tem de fazer uma avaliação para verificar se pode utilizá-la, uma vez que os resultados obtidos com o cache grind não serão iguais.
Segundo não desaloquei memória uma vez que afetaria os testes e neste caso isso é irrelevante, uma vez que o programa termina logo após a utilização doa dados alocados dinamicamente.

Comment: Opa tudo bem Gabriel, também fiquei assim quando ocorreu o erro de segmentação, como você comentou parece ser algo relacionado na alocação de memória, o mais interessante ainda é que mesmo mudando os valores de long double para int ainda assim o erro persiste, a possível solução é diminuir o tamanho da linha e coluna, como não gostaria de fazer isso ainda estou em busca de outra solução, sobre a sua solução acho que não posso usar por os resultados obtidos iram afetar a analise.

Comment: Entendo, bom de qualquer modo se eu conseguir encontrar outra solução eu posto aqui.